# .pdf to .txt and back again (encoding issues)

Tags: python, pdf, encoding, decoding, txt

I'm trying to use the refextract Python library to extract references from a bunch of reports. These reports come in both .docx and .pdf formats.

I've noticed that I get better performance from refextract when I convert the .pdf files to .txt and then back to .pdf (I suspect this has to do with the variety of ways that these .pdf files are originally converted from Word and this removes a tonne of "junk"). However, I'm running into encoding and decoding issues.

I'm creating the text files like this:

```
import fitz
import glob
import os

pdf_files = glob.glob(path + r'\*.pdf')       
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    with open(pdf_file[:-4]+'.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
        for page in doc:
            outfile.write(page.get_text())
        doc.close()
    os.remove(pdf_file)
```

However, when I try to convert this back into a .pdf (using the following code):

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import glob
import os

txt_files = glob.glob(path + r'\*.txt')
for txt_file in txt_files:
    pdf=FPDF()
    doc=[]
    with open (txt_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        print(txt_file)
        doc = infile.read()
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.set_font('Arial', size=12)
        pdf.write(5, doc)
        pdf.output(txt_file[:-4]+'.pdf')
    os.remove(txt_file)
```

I get the following error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 120-121: ordinal not in range(256)"

I've tried messing with the encoding by changing it to 'latin-1' using the following code after I've read the text file in:

```
doc = doc.encode('latin-1')
```

When I do this I end up with the following error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 44: ordinal not in range(256)". This file has no euro symbols in the original pdf so I'm extracting something else.

This encoding and decoding is clearly causing me a problem.  Any ideas or information would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You are making it unnecessarily complicated: text extraction with PyMuPDF automatically is UTF8 encoded. So define the output as `out = open("output.txt", "wb")` and write strings to it after converting them to bytes: `.encode()`. On re-opening that output file, similarly specify "rb" as reading mode. When reading such a file, you will get `bytes` objects (not strings). So, you must decode each input recod via `.decode("utf8")` to get a Unicode string again.

Comment: Your input PDF contains the Euro symbol € (= 0x20ac). So the output text file consists of Unicodes beyond the value 255 (the limit for simple fonts). Choose a richer font.

Comment: @JorjMcKie I concede that I am likely making this more difficult, but I don't see how storing my file as bytes vs text mode fixes the issue. I am still encountering the issue when I get to the .txt to .pdf conversion that there are characters that can't be converted. Please also see my original post where I stated that the original pdf file had no euro symbols.

Regardless, thank you for responding.  Every little insight helps.

Comment: You are right: The re-insertion of Unicode strings that contain codes beyond the 255 range will not work when using a simple font. So you **_could_** check whether there are characters having " ord(c) > 255" in your string. Then replace them by e.g. "?" - or, in case of `ord(0x20ac)` by `chr(0x80)` ... if you cannot use an "adult" font that supports enough Unicodes.